# Need to encrypt and decrypt in Java, unable to use Base64... I think

Tags: java, eclipse, encryption, base64

I need to encrypt and decrypt as four digit pin into a database and am having trouble. I have tried using examples that use Base64, put even after importing the package it can't find the class. What am I doing wrong? I understand that the class below may be correct, but why can't it find the class and create an object. In eclipse when I navigate to the Base64 class in reference libraries it says "source not found".

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class PasswordEncryption {

    private static Random random = new Random((new Date()).getTime());

    public static String encrypt(String userId) {  
        Base64() encoder = new Base64();
        byte[] salt = new byte[8];
        random.nextBytes(salt);
        return encoder.encode(salt)+
        encoder.encode(userId.getBytes());
    }

    public static String decrypt(String encryptKey) {
        if (encryptKey.length() > 12) {
            String cipher = encryptKey.substring(12);
            BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
            try {
                return new String(decoder.decodeBuffer(cipher));
            } catch (IOException e) {
                //  throw new InvalidImplementationException(
                //    "Failed to perform decryption for key ["+encryptKey+"]",e);
            }
        }         
        return null;
    }
}
```

And apologies if I have not used these forums correctly, this is my first post.

Thanks

Comment: Don't use Base64, it is an encoder not an encryption.

Comment: Oh, what a noob I feel... I'll google a more appropriate class to use. Unless you know of one that would be best?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to download [Apache Commons Codec](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/download_codec.cgi). After you've downloaded the jar, you need to add it to your Eclipse project as a library in your build path. (I apologise if you've already done this. It isn't clear from your post.)

Once you've done you still won't be able to see the source in Eclipse, but your project should work when you run it.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I was not clear in my post. I have downloaded and added the jar to my project library. It seems to import the package fine. (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64). But when I try to create a Base64 object, it is not recognized.

Comment: @JoeChamberlain Strange... It sounds very much like it's not on the classpath. Perhaps remove the import declaration of `Base64` and do a CTRL+SHIFT+o to make sure you're picking up the correct class. Anyhow, it sounds as though you wish to encrypt (opposed to encode)!

Comment: On another go. The class is being imported correctly, the example I have been using has been using it incorrectly I think. It works when I access the class statically instead of creating an instance.

Comment: Yeah, I'm so new to this. I shall research into hashing. Apologies if I have wasted your time. :)

Comment: Thanks all. I have ended up using BCrypt0.3 to hash the passwords. Very simple and from what I can see, secure.

Comment: @JoeChamberlain Glad you got it all sorted in the end. Yes, the Commons Codec API has changed a bit over the years. You didn't waste my time. Also, thanks for the update regarding BCrypt. I haven't used it before, but will keep it in mind.